# Using Athena searches on mixed data S3 Buckets

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Good day!

The question is: Does anyone know how to query JSON data with Athena on S3 buckets that contain not just JSON?

I been trying to create an Athena search in a bucket that has objects like this

```
S3Bucket
├── AFolder
│   ├── ExternalServiceID-1
│   │   ├── file-that-is-JSON
│   │   └── file-that-is-zip
│   ├── ExternalServiceID-2
│   │   ├── file-that-is-JSON
│   │   └── file-that-is-zip
│   └── ...
```

The Athena search I want to do is on a table that tries to project some simple properties of the `files-that-is-JSON`.

The table was created like this (more properties but they are all the same structure), note the statement on the end which is by documentation what is supposed to be done to ignore non-json data:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable(
         person struct <
            firstname: string,
            lastname: string,
         >
)
ROW FORMAT  serde 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
with serdeproperties ( 'ignore.malformed.json'='true' )
```

However, when running a query with any `WHERE` clause, I get the error `HIVE_BAD_DATA: Error parsing field value for field 1: Data is not JSONObject but java.lang.String with value H` which would signal that the table is not being created correctly. An example of such query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM "workspace"."mytable"
WHERE person.firstname.value='Max'
AND person.lastName.value='Mustermann' limit 10;
```

If I don't use the struct like the one I described at the table creation, then I don't have the error, but I naturally lose the ability to query with specific values.

Answer (score 0):

Your storage format is not compatible with Amazon Athena.

All files relating to one table need to be in one directory.

Therefore, all files in that path need to be of identical format.

If you are wanting to query across the multiple JSON files you have shown, where each of them are in directories with the zip files, Amazon Athena cannot be used.

Comment: Question then: I have previously done other queries that have the data distributed in different folders. Also, if that was the case, why does it work when I simplify the structure of the table?Maybe you could show me where is stated the way data should be structured since I am working on restructuring the service that creates the data and this information could influence the new design. Thank you!

Comment: Amazon Athena reads all files in the nominated directory, including sub-directories. Any objects in those paths need to be the same format. If you managed to get it working differently, then you probably know more about how to do it than I do.